# How do i get the play button to only work once?

Tags: java

This is my code for the play button:

```
//PLAY
    if(mouseOver(mx, my, 260, 100, 100, 50)) {
        this.game.gameState = Game.STATE.Game;
        this.handler.addObject(new Player(this.game.WIDTH/2-32, this.game.HEIGHT/2-32, ID.Player,this.handler));

    }
```

The problem with that is when the game mode changes from the menu to the game, the play button still remains there, yet invisible. So I can still press it and more and more players are created. How do I get it to only work once, and stop once the player is created?

Comment: if its a `JButton`, you can call `setEnabled(false);`. This way you stop the button from being clickable

Comment: The dirty way -> create a `boolean isFirst=true;` and when you click the first time you check if it is at true, before creating the Player you put it at `false`.

`//PLAY
    if(mouseOver(mx, my, 260, 100, 100, 50)) {
        if(isFirst){
        this.game.gameState=Game.STATE.Game;
        this.handler.addObject(new Player(this.game.WIDTH/2-32, this.game.HEIGHT/2-32, ID.Player,this.handler));
isFirst=false;
}
    }`

The good way is to remove that button completely or disable it.